# Jenkins Xcode building fail on Mac, But the same command used in terminal on local is ok

Tags: xcode, jenkins, devops

I used Jenkins build xcode project on Mac, It's fail:
"error: unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Build again to continue."

But I use same command in terminal on local Mac, It's ok.

I don't know, what is different?
How fix it?

Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 6149****-****-****-****-1bf29c30****

> git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4/.git # timeout=10
> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/WangYong22/test4.git # timeout=10
> Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/WangYong22/test4.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)'
> using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials GitHubFullToken
> git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/WangYong22/test4.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
> Checking out Revision d24d6953f4e2a07b58dea3c9856434624b5485de (refs/remotes/origin/main)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f d24d6953f4e2a07b58dea3c9856434624b5485de # timeout=10
> Commit message: "delete testUI and tests target"
> git rev-list --no-walk d24d6953f4e2a07b58dea3c9856434624b5485de # timeout=10
> Working directory is /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4.
> Fetching marketing version number (CFBundleShortVersionString) from project.
> [DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/agvtool mvers -terse1
> No marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) found.
> Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) found in project configuration:
> Fetching technical version number (CFBundleVersion) from project.
> [DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/agvtool vers -terse
> Found technical version (CFBundleVersion): 1
> Technical version (CFBundleVersion) found in project configuration: 1.
> Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA:
> Technical version (CFBundleVersion) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: 1
> == Can we find the requested developer certificate ?
> [DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/security find-certificate -a -c ******** -Z | grep ^SHA-1
> == Available SDKs
> [DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -showsdks
> DriverKit SDKs:
> DriverKit 23.0                  -sdk driverkit23.0

iOS SDKs:
iOS 17.0                        -sdk iphoneos17.0

iOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - iOS 17.0            -sdk iphonesimulator17.0

macOS SDKs:
macOS 14.0                      -sdk macosx14.0
macOS 14.0                      -sdk macosx14.0

tvOS SDKs:
tvOS 17.0                       -sdk appletvos17.0

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - tvOS 17.0           -sdk appletvsimulator17.0

watchOS SDKs:
watchOS 10.0                    -sdk watchos10.0

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - watchOS 10.0        -sdk watchsimulator10.0

== Available schemes
[DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Information about project "test4":
Targets:
test4
test4Tests
test4UITests

```
Build Configurations:
    Debug
    Release

If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

Schemes:
    test4
```

## == Available parameters
[DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -help
-usage
-help
-verbose
-license
-checkFirstLaunchStatus
-runFirstLaunch
-downloadAllPlatforms
-downloadPlatform
-downloadAllPreviouslySelectedPlatforms
-project
-target
-alltargets
-workspace
-scheme
-configuration
-xcconfig
-arch
-sdk
-toolchain
-destination
-destination-timeout
-parallelizeTargets
-jobs
-maximum-concurrent-test-device-destinations
-maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations
-parallel-testing-enabled
-parallel-testing-worker-count
-maximum-parallel-testing-workers
-dry-run
-quiet
-hideShellScriptEnvironment
-showsdks
-showdestinations
-showTestPlans
-showBuildSettings
-showBuildSettingsForIndex
-list
-find-executable
-find-library
-version
-enableAddressSanitizer
-enableThreadSanitizer
-enableUndefinedBehaviorSanitizer
-resultBundlePath
-resultStreamPath
-resultBundleVersion
-clonedSourcePackagesDirPath
-derivedDataPath
-archivePath
-exportArchive
-exportNotarizedApp
-exportOptionsPlist
-enableCodeCoverage
-exportPath
-skipUnavailableActions
-exportLocalizations
-importLocalizations
-localizationPath
-exportLanguage
-defaultLanguage
-xctestrun
-testProductsPath
-enablePerformanceTestsDiagnostics
-testPlan
-only-testing
-only-testing:TEST-IDENTIFIER
-skip-testing
-skip-testing:TEST-IDENTIFIER
-test-timeouts-enabled
-default-test-execution-time-allowance
-maximum-test-execution-time-allowance
-test-iterations
-retry-tests-on-failure
-run-tests-until-failure
-test-repetition-relaunch-enabled
-only-test-configuration
-skip-test-configuration
-collect-test-diagnostics
-testLanguage
-testRegion
-enumerate-tests
-test-enumeration-style
-test-enumeration-format
-test-enumeration-output-path
-resolvePackageDependencies
-disableAutomaticPackageResolution
-onlyUsePackageVersionsFromResolvedFile
-skipPackageUpdates
-disablePackageRepositoryCache
-skipPackagePluginValidation
-skipMacroValidation
-packageCachePath
-defaultPackageRegistryURL
-packageDependencySCMToRegistryTransformation
-skipPackageSignatureValidation
-packageFingerprintPolicy
-packageSigningEntityPolicy
-json
-allowProvisioningUpdates
-allowProvisioningDeviceRegistration
-authenticationKeyPath
-authenticationKeyID
-authenticationKeyIssuerID
-scmProvider
-showBuildTimingSummary
-create-xcframework

## buildDirectory: /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4/build/Debug-iphoneos
[DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 15.0.1
Build version 15A507
Cleaning build directory: /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4/build/Debug-iphoneos
[DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/security list-keychains -s ${HOME}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
[DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/security default-keychain -d user -s ${HOME}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
[DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/security unlock-keychain -p ******** ${HOME}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
[DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/security show-keychain-info ${HOME}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
Keychain "/Users/test/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db" no-timeout

== Certificates available for the Codesign
[DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v

1. 974293B5D683E9F321FFC0F262E**** "Apple Distribution: Yong **** (******)"
2. 9D047A9BA1E822D083B19429FD80**** "Developer ID Application: Yong **** (******)"
3. F39EA8174BC940F3728B0F9B12**** "Apple Development: Yong **** (******)"
   3 valid identities found
   Going to invoke xcodebuild:, scheme: test4, sdk: DEFAULT, project: DEFAULT, configuration: Debug, clean: YES, archive:YES, consolelog:YES, symRoot: DEFAULT, buildDir: DEFAULT, developmentTeamID: ****, allowProvisioningUpdates: YES, useLegacyBuildSystem: YES
   [DevOpsTest4] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme test4 -configuration Debug clean archive -archivePath /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4/build/Debug-iphoneos/test4.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=***** -allowProvisioningUpdates -UseModernBuildSystem=NO
   Command line invocation:
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme test4 -configuration Debug clean archive -archivePath /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4/build/Debug-iphoneos/test4.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=**** -allowProvisioningUpdates -UseModernBuildSystem=NO

User defaults from command line:
IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4/build/Debug-iphoneos/test4.xcarchive
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
UseModernBuildSystem = NO

Build settings from command line:
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = ****

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00006021-001C18AA36BB401E }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00006021-001C18AA36BB401E }
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:macOS, name:Any Mac }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C9B8EF1F-1736-4BFD-95C0-DCA69EF2EA94, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad (10th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C9B8EF1F-1736-4BFD-95C0-DCA69EF2EA94, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad (10th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3A7BAEF3-C2D5-4505-BFED-A71824557B03, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3A7BAEF3-C2D5-4505-BFED-A71824557B03, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:54879D86-1DDC-494C-84E4-44D083D7E6A5, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:54879D86-1DDC-494C-84E4-44D083D7E6A5, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F94FCC9A-306C-445D-9DE7-97DAEDC5B587, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F94FCC9A-306C-445D-9DE7-97DAEDC5B587, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3F15F8B1-A4B4-467F-B978-FC6D171B6819, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3F15F8B1-A4B4-467F-B978-FC6D171B6819, OS:17.0.1, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0DBBC7B0-5AD9-42CA-BB82-3CD9FF2E59DC, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0DBBC7B0-5AD9-42CA-BB82-3CD9FF2E59DC, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:84A90ABD-A424-4FB8-B59B-31644DEFC63D, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:84A90ABD-A424-4FB8-B59B-31644DEFC63D, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:EE63F3C6-942D-4D72-A64D-15599701F180, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:EE63F3C6-942D-4D72-A64D-15599701F180, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:721E0E81-D4FF-4D42-AEE8-61913B6A27E6, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:721E0E81-D4FF-4D42-AEE8-61913B6A27E6, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4C0C41C2-1779-4840-A899-7D242BE88208, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4C0C41C2-1779-4840-A899-7D242BE88208, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
error: unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Build again to continue.

** CLEAN FAILED **

I used this command in terminal on local Mac is ok.

/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme test4 -configuration Debug clean archive -archivePath /Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/DevOpsTest4/build/Debug-iphoneos/test4.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=***** -allowProvisioningUpdates -UseModernBuildSystem=NO

** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **